# sbt org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;${slf4j.version}: not found

Tags: maven, hbase, sbt, slf4j, pom.xml

I need to get hbase 0.92.2 using sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "0.92.2",
```

But I got this error when i run the update:

0.92.2 hbase  org.slf4j#slf4j-log4j12;${slf4j.version}: not found

I checked on the pom file for hbase 0.92.2 and it has

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

the pom file is provided by the remove repository. I am not sure how to specify the version for slf4j, so the sbt can get right version without  complains.

Answer (score 1):

I created a `build.sbt` with only one line:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "0.92.2"
```

Then I ran:

```
sbt -Dslf4j.version=1.4.3 update
```

That worked out well!

I even tried with this:

```
sbt -Dslf4j.version=1.6.6 update
```

That worked too.

Comment: @user1588745 Accept this as an answer in that case. Look here how to: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the slf4j.version property in the pom like so:

```
<properties>
     <slf4j.version>1.7.2</slf4j.version>
<properties>
```

I set the property value to 1.7.2 which is the latest slf4j version.  You should choose the appropriate version for your situation.

EDIT:

Try grabbing a later version of hbase if you can.  The later versions have slf4j.version declared in the base build profile.

EDIT:

I also believe sbt has a way to add information to the pom via the pomExtra and pomPostProcess of BasicManagedProject.

Check that out and you may be able to add the properties node for slf4j.version.  I'm guessing here as I am not an sbt expert.

Comment: the pom file is provided by the remove repository.  I thought i could have a way to provide the version in the run time.

Comment: Have you tried getting a later version of hbase or do you need that particular version?  The later pom has the version declared in the base profile.

Comment: Thank you gwhitake. I need that particular version. or I should say i need a hbase version with slf4j.version > 1.6.